# How to calculate sums like $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ sinc (-4 \cdot \pi (n-3)(n-4) ) }{n(n-1)} $ with the Residue Theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, residue-calculus, trigonometric-series

I'm trying to compute sums like $$S:= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ \operatorname{sinc} (-4\pi (n-3)(n-4) ) }{n(n-1)} $$
by means of the Residue Theorem, which states that $$\lim_{k \to +\infty} \sum_{k=-N}^{N} f(k) = - \{ \text{sum of the residues of } \pi f(z) \cot(\pi z) \text{ at the poles of }f(z) \} .$$
Here, $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \sin(x)/x $ at $x \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} $, and $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = 1$ at $x = 0$.

I'm having some trouble determining the nature and degree of the poles, and how to use the cotangent function as well. Considering the definition of the sinc function, we could rewrite the sum as follows:

$$S = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(-4\pi (n-3)(n-4))}{-4 \pi n(n-1)(n-3)(n-4)} ,$$ so if we'd take $$f(z) = \frac{\sin(-4\pi(z-3)(z-4))}{-4 \pi z(z-1)(z-3)(z-4)}, $$ we can use the Residue Theorem to compute $S$, as $f$ amounts to zero when $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{< 0}$. Thus, I would guess that the poles of $f$ are at $z=0, z=1, z=3,$ and $z=4$, and are all of order $1$.

However, I'm not quite sure how to calculate the residues when the cotangent function is involved. I know the residues of $\pi f(z) \cot(\pi z) $ amount to $\frac{7}{12}, -\frac{10}{12}, \frac{2}{12},$ and $\frac{1}{12} $ at $z=0,1,3,4$ respectively by calculating them in WolframAlpha, but I'm not entirely sure how the software computes them. Does it use the Taylor series of the cotangent function for this? How can these residues be calculated by hand?

Moreover, the sum of the residues as described above amounts to zero. However, I know it must be the case that $S=\frac{1}{4}$, as the sum only has nonzero terms when the arguments of the sinc function are zero, which happens at $n=3$ and $n=4$. Thus, $S=\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{4}$.

I do see that the sum of the residues at $z=0$ and $z=1$ give the correct evaluation for $S$, but then I fail to see why the residues of the other two poles at $z=3$ and $z=4$ must be discarded.

**Questions**:

1. What exactly are the poles of $f$, and what are their degrees?
2. How do I take into account the $\cot(\pi z)$ function when computing the residues?

Comment: To make it look nice use `\operatorname{sinc}`.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Hmm I'm not entirely sure how to apply this hint, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it was the justification for a correct version of your formula. But (i) you should be planning to integrate $\pi\cot\pi z f(z)$ round a big square as usual (ii) there are poles at the integers (iii) apart from $n=0,\pm 1$ the residues are $f(n)$ [$n=3,4$ are NOT poles of $f(z)$] (iv) the three exceptional poles are (I think) double poles, so use your favourite trick to evaluate their residues (v) $f$ is even so replace the doubly infinite sum by an infinite one.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thank you for your reply. I wonder: why is $n=-1$ also a pole, and how is it exceptional?

Comment: More specifically on (i), $f(z)$ has to vanish at complex-infinite $z$, or you may have to handle the respective integrals manually. Neither seems to work for *your* $f(z)$, so the approach "breaks" there.

Comment: @metamorphy so are you saying the residue theorem can't be applied to find the sum? I mean, it works when one adds the residues at z=0 and z=1, no?

Comment: And I mean that the application is not justified. And the "theorem" doesn't hold without any additional assumptions on $f$ (consider $f(z)=\operatorname{sinc}\pi z$ which has no poles).

Comment: @metamorphy do you know why it seems to yield the correct answer - even though the theorem strictly cannot be applied in this case? And are there perhaps generalizations or variations of the theorem for which my choice of $f$ does satisfy the appropriate assumptions?